# How to join document in search query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "product_index",
        "_type": "product",
        "_id": "1115",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "isactive": true,
          "in_use": false,
          "brand_name": "Adidas",
          "sku_id": "56456487987987",
          "long_description": "this is long description",
          "key_feature": [
            {
              "id": 1148,
              "key_feature": "sport wear"
            },
            {
              "id": 1147,
              "key_feature": "Cotton shirt"
            },
            {
              "id": 1146,
              "key_feature": "White and blue"
            }
          ],
          "isdeleted": false,
          "created_by": null,
          "brand_id": 5,
          "search_terms": [
            {
              "label": "white shirt",
              "value": 9
            }
          ]
          "color_id": 2,
          "specific_keywords": "",
          "item_list": [
            {
              "item_id": 1114,
              "product_id": 1115,
              "isactive": true,
              "id": 9,
              "isdeleted": false
            },
            {
              "item_id": 1113,
              "product_id": 1115,
              "isactive": true,
              "id": 10,
              "isdeleted": false
            }
          ],
          "upc_code": "",
          "display_size": "L",
          "name": "New White shirt",
          "updated_by": null,
          "id": 1115,
          "updated_date": "2020-03-25T08:24:37.644571+00:00",
          "color_name": "blue",
          "created_date": "2020-03-25T08:11:14.966673+00:00",
          "category": [
            {
              "parent_category_id": 78,
              "sub_sub_category": null,
              "sub_category": null,
              "sub_category_id": null,
              "sub_sub_category_id": null,
              "parent_category": "new Shirt Cate",
              "id": 1151
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product_index",
        "_type": "product",
        "_id": "1113",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "isactive": true,
          "in_use": false,
          "sku_id": "1456456488",
          "brand_name": "Adidas",
          "long_description": "",
          "key_feature": [
            {
              "id": 1142,
              "key_feature": "Cotton"
            },
            {
              "id": 1141,
              "key_feature": "Office Use"
            },
            {
              "id": 1140,
              "key_feature": "Black formal"
            }
          ],
          "isdeleted": false,
          "created_by": null,
          "brand_id": 5,
          "search_terms": [

          ]
          "color_id": 1,
          "specific_keywords": "",
          "item_list": [

          ],
          "display_size": "L",
          "upc_code": "",
          "name": "New Cotton formal shirt black",
          "updated_by": null,
          "id": 1113,
          "updated_date": "2020-03-25T06:48:30.903041+00:00",
          "created_date": "2020-03-25T06:48:29.943043+00:00",
          "color_name": "black",
          "category": [
            {
              "sub_sub_category": null,
              "parent_category_id": 54,
              "sub_category": null,
              "sub_category_id": null,
              "sub_sub_category_id": null,
              "parent_category": "MEN'S CLOTHING",
              "id": 1149
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product_index",
        "_type": "product",
        "_id": "1114",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "isactive": true,
          "in_use": false,
          "sku_id": "145645648811",
          "brand_name": "Adidas",
          "long_description": "",
          "key_feature": [
            {
              "id": 1145,
              "key_feature": "Cotton"
            },
            {
              "id": 1144,
              "key_feature": "Office Use"
            },
            {
              "id": 1143,
              "key_feature": "Black formal"
            }
          ],
          "isdeleted": false,
          "created_by": null,
          "brand_id": 5,
          "search_terms": [

          ],
          "color_id": 1,
          "specific_keywords": "",
          "item_list": [

          ],
          "display_size": "L",
          "upc_code": "",
          "updated_by": null,
          "name": "New Cotton Casual shirt black",
          "id": 1114,
          "created_date": "2020-03-25T07:13:26.233675+00:00",
          "color_name": "black",
          "updated_date": "2020-03-25T07:13:27.229363+00:00",
          "category": [
            {
              "sub_sub_category": null,
              "parent_category_id": 54,
              "sub_category": null,
              "sub_category_id": null,
              "sub_sub_category_id": null,
              "parent_category": "MEN'S CLOTHING",
              "id": 1150
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my requirement is to attach all related documents with specific key value fields which is specify in item_list based on item_id. In above result doc id 1115 has item_list which contains item_id 1114 and 1113. so the particular fields attach in the doc 1115.
what should be the search query for that in elastic search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do join in Elasticsearch, to achieve your goal, you can do two things:

1. duplicate the information of item_id 1114 and 1113 in the item_id
   1115 (and for sure in all others documents).
2. Do join at application level, so after this query you can extract the item_id 1114 and 1113 and run two others query to get the information about this items. Then join all the json at application level.

Comment: shall we uses nasted query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html or has_child query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html I tried but i got error.

Comment: Yes you can use nested query too, but you'll have queries more slow than a flatten solution.What kind of error do you have?

Comment: first i tried to do nested query manually. my query is {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"id":1115}}]},"nested":{"path":"","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"id":1114}}]}},"score_mode":"avg"}}}  and i got {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":51}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":51},"status":400}

Comment: You need to redesign your index to achieve your goal. I really suggest to duolicate the necessary information into the nested documents.

Comment: I used 2 one.It is more suitable then duplication.